# finding one string within a list of others strings

Tags: python, string, substring

I'm trying to create a new list from an original list but am having some difficulties.

The list is as follows `list1 = [training, bicycle, working, carrying, bite, eat]`

my new list called ing is designed to only sort out the words containing ing within it so the new list should look like this `[training, working, carrying]`

the code looks as follows

```
def ing(lists):
     b = "ing"
     for d in lists:
        if b in d:
            print(d)

        else:
           continue




    return (lists)
```

when running this with list1, it pretty much prints out list1 rather than isolating the word containing ing.
The problem area appears to be the line

```
          if b in d:
```

is there are better way of writing a sorting out a list based on the words within that list as this seems to be the only way

Comment: Are you not returning the original lists without modifying it? Is it not printing out correct words? Also, why so many empty lines before return statement?

Comment: no i am returning the original list. it just that I'm trying to get a new list with words that only contain ing in this instance

Comment: You should run above code and post in the question what it prints out.

Comment: it will print out list1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do with a method call - Just have your method return a new list with elements of the old list satisfying the search criteria.

Something like:

```
def ing(lists):
    b = "ing"
    new_list = []
    for d in lists:
        if b in d:
            print(d)
            new_list.append(d)

         else:
             continue



     return new_list

list1 = ['training', 'bicycle', 'working', 'carrying', 'bite', 'eat']
new_list = ing(list1)
print new_list
```

The list output of the code above is:

> ['training', 'working', 'carrying']

Doing with a list comprehension works as well as shown by @cricket_007

Comment: thanks for the help man. unfortunately, when running this i found that it only prints the first word of the list e.g. training as opposed to creating a whole new list with all words containing ing.

Comment: That's odd, I verified this code in a Jupyter notebook under Python 2.7

Comment: Sure, please consider accepting if the answer helped you, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're never making a new list, only printing things

Try this

```
list1 = ["training" , "bicycle", "working", "carrying", "bite" , "eat"]
ing = [x for x in list1 if "ing" in x]
print(ing)
```

Or if you insist on having a function

```
def filter_ing(l);
    return [x for x in l if "ing" in x]
```

Comment: thanks for the help man. only issue with this is that I'm not really defining a function using this method, rather just printing a new list. i want to create a function that can be used over and over

Comment: Okay, then define a function to run the list comprehension

Answer (score 0):

try this one (New way with similarity to you code)

```
    def ing(l):
        new=[]
        b="ing"
        for d in l:
            if b in d:
                new.append(d)#I am adding the wording ending with 'ing' to a new list
    #you were missing appending
        print(new)

    l= ['training','bicycle','working','carrying','bite','eat']
    ing(l)#calling_function
```

The thing you were missing was that you the list you given doesn't consist of string. To put them in string use ' ' or " " as I have done above.

Also, when you are using return then there should be some thing to hold that specific return. You didn't use such thing.

Still any doubt, Feels free to ask via comment. Happy to help.

Comment: thanks man but found that paisanos link worked best. thanks again though

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions:

```
import re
l= ['training','bicycle','working','carrying','bite','eat']
new_l = filter(lambda x:re.findall('ing$', x), l)
```

Output:

```
['training', 'working', 'carrying']
```